# Rhythmbox does not remember my music

Tags: mp3, music-player

I am adding my music stored in an NTFS drive into Rhythmbox. It stays in the library for that session. However, when I shut down and restart, all imported music is lost from the library (even after mounting the NTFS drive and opening Rhythmbox then). The library is not saved and I can't make a playlist.

Is this problem common? Is there a solution to it?

Comment: Is this NTFS partition a partition on your HDD? Or is it on an external drive?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what "not saved" means here? The music doesn't appear at all after rebooting? The music is listed in the UI, but it does not play, instead resulting in a `Missing Files` source in the sources tree, that lists all the music?

Comment: Did you solved your problem? I'm having the same problem. Once restarted, the library is gone. It's happening in all the music players I tried

Answer (score 5):

Open Rhythmbox, click Edit --> Preferences --> Music Tab, and point the Library Location to the music library in whatever directory you have the music stored in.

Comment: This is not necessary. Rhythmbox does not require music in the library, to be underneath the configured "default" location. It can be anywhere.

Comment: And I can repro the original poster issue with an external disk folder declared there in the preference.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but it's still valid.

After you import your music and see all your files listed, you have to click the "Import Discovered Files" button to permenantly add the music to your library.