# Resume from suspend not working and Rhythmbox loses all files on reboot

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 15.04, suspend

PC: Sony vaio VGN-FW250j

CPU: Intel Duo Core 64 bit system

OS: Windows 7 Installed

OS: Ubuntu 15.04 from amd64 ISO via UNetbootin "frugal boot" method.

Dual Boot: Ubuntu 15.04 as well as Windows 7 **are** bootable

My current disk and partitions are like this:

```
sudo blkid -c /dev/null 
/dev/sda1: LABEL="System Reserved" UUID="1E98FB2198FAF5DD" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="a287a9ef-01"    
/dev/sda2: UUID="6016FE5E16FE349E" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="a287a9ef-02"
/dev/sda4: LABEL="Swap" UUID="b246d9d7-15ea-48c1-8313-c4cbeafb8a3a" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="a287a9ef-04"    
/dev/sda5: UUID="b010e611-6efb-49a9-bff0-59b9533d659b" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="a287a9ef-05"
```

Are there any problems you see here? My **Resume** from suspend does not work and **Rhythmbox** loses all the previously imported files every time I reboot.  I have verified the swap space is on and working, and the resume, grub and fstab files use the resume=UUID=abc...xyz" of the swap file.

I would like to have suspend working but can live without it since the boot time is pretty fast.

Here is my fstab file:

> /etc/fstab: static file system information.
>
> Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
> device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
> that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
>
> file system mount point   type  options       dump  pass
>
> / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
>
> UUID=b010e611-6efb-49a9-bff0-59b9533d659b /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
> UUID=b246d9d7-15ea-48c1-8313-c4cbeafb8a3a none swap sw 0 0

I am wondering if part of the issue is that my fstab file is not configured to help Ubuntu read/write the NTFS (win 7) partition where the data files are stored and therefore Rhythmbox cannot properly import the files.

What do you think?

Comment: Is the music from RythmBox stored on an NTFS partition or locally on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were two questions in my original post having to do with:

1. Resuming from a suspend
2. Rhythmbox losing library after reboot

I was able to setup hibernate to work using the simple instructions found here: https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-help/power-hibernate.html

Suspend, technically is still not working, however, I found that Hibernate is an equivalent for my purposes so I am satisfied with this alternative. The helpful link above I followed pretty much verbatim.

First, I did have to setup my swap file to be sure it would be used to store files during a hibernate in order for it to resume later.  For that I used the info in this link:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq

As far as Rhythmbox losing its library after reboot I was able to overcome this issue as well.  I believe the main issue here was the linked files becoming unlinked during the reboot, an issue that really has nothing to do with Rhythmbox or any other music player/manager.

However the issue is related to a dual boot Win7/Linux system. I did not have the NTFS volume, where the library (actual music files) were located configured or set to mount upon reboot.  There were a few other things I learned along the way.

In order to solve this issue I followed some helpful links:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions

I created a shared partition in Windows and named it Data.  I then moved my music, pictures, documents, downloads, and videos to this NTFS volume.  I used Gparted Live cd to add a /home and a new swap volume.  I then configured the ftsab, grub, and initramfs files to setup the new swap for a resume state per the swapfaq link above.  Then I created a mountpoint

> sudo mkdir /media/Data

where the Data volume would mount on reboot. I added

> UUID=F0EAFE30EAFDF2A8                     /media/Data     ntfs-3g defaults,windows_names,locale=en_US.utf8  0       0

To fstab to actually mount the volume per the info in the Mounting Windows Partitions help wiki above.

My volumes look like this now:

> /dev/sda1: LABEL="System Reserved" UUID="1E98FB2198FAF5DD" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="a287a9ef-01"
>
> /dev/sda2: LABEL="Win7OS" UUID="6016FE5E16FE349E" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="a287a9ef-02"
>
> /dev/sda3: LABEL="Data" UUID="F0EAFE30EAFDF2A8" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="a287a9ef-03"
>
> /dev/sda5: LABEL="Ubuntu" UUID="b010e611-6efb-49a9-bff0-59b9533d659b" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="a287a9ef-05"
>
> /dev/sda6: LABEL="HOME" UUID="3cd8964d-59e2-43e3-8f15-bee9600f95b3" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="a287a9ef-06"
>
> /dev/sda7: LABEL="Swap" UUID="8bcb4169-f5ab-4ab6-b644-23e528088d41" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="a287a9ef-07"

My Hibernate works and my Rhythmbox does not lose any of the library files after rebooting.  Thanks to those that made comments and helped me direct my attention where it needed to be.  I hope this helps others in future.

Answer (score 0):

So there are a couple things you can do here. First for Rythmbox this could be a duplicate issue of: [Rythmbox Does Not Remember My Music](https://askubuntu.com/questions/287383/rhythmbox-does-not-remember-my-music). See if the solution here has provided your fix. Pointing Rythmbox to the location of your files should store the session for future use.

As for the resume on suspend there was an issues in an older version of Ubuntu, but it should have been fixed. Try using the solution here: [Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Suspend Not Working FIX](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1978290). I have used this script on an older laptop running prior versions of Ubuntu that had this issue and I had no further issues. It's more or less a work around, but it worked for me. I have not tried this on the newer version of Ubuntu.

Comment: I am wondering if Rhythmbox and Banshee are not read/writing the NTFS partition properly.  I am currently researching shared data partitioning.  Thanks for your help Joe

Comment: As long as they are mounted at startup, they are reading them correctly. But you have to mount them at startup. So, it the partition automatically mounted at startup or do you have to mount it by clicking on it?